# How to install G Suite Marketplace application from our website? (Integrate with google button)

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-authentication, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

I have configured my marketplace app, and I would like to let the user install the app through our website instead of going to G Suite marketplace at all.

I heard that Google has released this kind of functionality called "Integrate with google" in 2014 via this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvW4VO5a4w4&feature=youtu.be&t=347). But I was unable to find any documentation for this now.

[Documentation page](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/button) of this feature is giving 404 error as well.

Was this feature obsoleted already? or else can someone please help me configuring this option on my website.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I found the [answer](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2014/02/drive-google-apps-marketplace-installs.html). You just have to add the following two line into your page.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<div class="g-additnow" data-applicationid="your-app-id"></div>
```

App ID can be found in the top of Configuration in "G Suite Marketplace SDK"

[image]

But there is no google documentation for this.

Comment: This methods doesn't work now. Check this email thread.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220913951