# "Test installation flow"/"Integrate with Google" button missing

Tags: google-api, google-apps-marketplace

I'm working on a project, which integrates with some G Suite services, and is implemented using G Suite Marketplace SDK, so we can have it published on the GSM. We have unpublished versions of the app, which are used for testing.

Up until a few days ago, we were able to test the app, by going to Cloud Console at https://console.developers.google.com/, then to "G Suite Marketplace SDK", then to "Configuration", where we had a an "Integrate with Google" button. Earlier, this button had a "Test installation flow" label.

A few days ago, the button disappeared. No errors are shown. What I did notice as well, is that the Cloud Console UI changed as well (e.g. Configuration renamed to App Configuration, there's also a "Store listing" option etc.)

Does anyone have any idea about why the button might have disappeared?

Comment: There has been an update on the issue I created. Please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59642040/488666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Reported in Issue Tracker:

I have filed a bug in Issue Tracker regarding this behaviour:

- [Button “Integrate with Google” does not get displayed in the “Configuration” tab of Marketplace SDK](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161064018)

To anyone affected by this, I'd suggest clicking the star on the top-left of the referenced page, in order to keep track of its development and to prioritize it.

## Update from Issue Tracker: Marketplace SDK UI has recently changed:

The disappearance of this button is caused by a change in Marketplace SDK UI, which also explains the other changes you noticed (e.g. `App Configuration`). This from Issue Tracker:

> There as been an update in the UI, and the button `Integrate with Google` has been removed from the new UI.
> In any case, there are other ways to test add-ons before publishing them publicly (see [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing-gsm#before_you_publish)), including [installing an unpublished one](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons), deploying an [Apps Script web app for testing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app) or publishing the app privately so that it's only visible to users in your domain.
> As a sidenote, recording a video of an app is no longer required for OAuth review when trying to publish it to the Marketplace (for which this button was useful).

Comment: Thanks for that, that answers my initial question. However, changing the app visibility is not possible for me; it's greyed out: https://imgur.com/kG9MGz4 Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: @HarisOsmanagić You're welcome! About your other question, from the `App Visibility` section: `Warning: Once you choose a visibility option and save the App Configuration, you can't change your selection later.` [ref](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/sdk#about_app_configuration). So I'm afraid you should create another project if you want to change that.